# Why Flexslider direction buttons is not showing?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I try to display direction buttons in flexslider. When i check inspector  see that prev and next buttons has `flex-disabled` class and is not display.
I add `directionNav: true` to my js code but don't solved.
How to fixe this?
[My website](https://new.travelenter.com/Hotel/Hoteldetails?CityHotel=1134&FromDate=1395%2F05%2F30&Todate=1395%2F05%2F31&NumberOfRoom=1&Adult=1&Child=0&Infant=0&IsCity=false&hotelid=1134)

html:

```
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#">Previous</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a tabindex="-1" class="flex-next flex-disabled" href="#">Next</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
    $item.flexslider({
            animation: dataAnimation,
            directionNav: true,
            controlNav: true,
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            sync: dataSync,
            start: function (slider) {
                            if (typeof dataFixPos != "undefined" && dataFixPos == "1") {
                    var height = $(slider).find(".slides img").height();
                    $(slider).find(".flex-control-nav").css("top", (height - 44) + "px");

                }
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have display none property for class ".photo-gallery.style1 .flex-direction-nav" in your css.

change it form display:none to display:block

.photo-gallery.style1 .flex-direction-nav{display"block}

Comment: OK . This is right  but I should clear "flex-disabled"class